# Cakephp poll component

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins

is there such thing as cakephp poll plugin or poll code

for presenting online polls on the site ( giving the poll the options of answers and showing how many answerers chose which answer )

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that this would be very simple to write yourself. If you're a PHP novice then it would be an excellent exercise.

Answer (score 1):

[Croogo Poll Plugin that can be adapted to CakePHP](https://github.com/chroposnos/poll)